# Why does 0 integer value behaves as false in if statement in groovy?

Tags: if-statement, groovy

I wrote this part of code.

```
Integer value = 0

if(value) {
    print "true"
} else {
    print "false"
}
```

And the output of code is `false`.
Can someone explain me why does Integer 0 value behaves as false in this if statement when it is not null and it exists?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Groovy sees a variable in the context where a boolean value is expected, it invokes `DefaultGroovyMethods.asBoolean(object)` method to coerce given value to its boolean representation. For numbers following code gets executed:

```
/**
 * Coerce a number to a boolean value.
 * A number is coerced to false if its double value is equal to 0, and to true otherwise,
 * and to true otherwise.
 *
 * @param number the number
 * @return the boolean value
 * @since 1.7.0
 */
public static boolean asBoolean(Number number) {
    return number.doubleValue() != 0;
}
```

*Source: [src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L10768-L10774)*

That is why Groovy coerce 0 to `false` and any non-zero number to `true`.

There are other coercions that Groovy mades for you, e.g. empty list coerces to `false`, empty string coerces to `false` etc. I have written an [article about some of them](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/2018/09/groovy-dynamic-types-coercion-and-promotion-you-have-been-warned/), you might find it useful.

Answer (score 5):

It's part of the "[Groovy Truth](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth)"

> 5.7. Numbers
>
> Non-zero numbers are true.
>
> ```
> assert 1
> assert 3.5
> assert !0
> ```